# Convert Java Swing to JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, computer-science

I modified the classic snake game where I have an eagle fly down to attack the snake. I also allowed the snake to be able to attack/shoot the eagle as well. I have the code written in Java Swing and need help converting to JavaFX. I also been trying to give the snake 3 lives before Game over. Would be great help just converting to JavaFX. I'm mostly not sure how I would get my images where I used ImageIcon into JavaFx as well as converting my Runner code. Also I'm not looking to use FXML if possible.

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Random;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Panel extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener{
    ImageIcon title = new ImageIcon("/Users/jessi/eclipse-workspace/updatedSnake/src/title.jpg");
    ImageIcon body = new ImageIcon("/Users/jessi/eclipse-workspace/updatedSnake/src/body.png");
    ImageIcon right = new ImageIcon("/Users/jessi/eclipse-workspace/updatedSnake/src/right.png");
    ImageIcon left = new ImageIcon("/Users/jessi/eclipse-workspace/updatedSnake/src/left.png");
    ImageIcon up = new ImageIcon("/Users/jessi/eclipse-workspace/updatedSnake/src/up.png");
    ImageIcon down = new ImageIcon("/Users/jessi/eclipse-workspace/updatedSnake/src/down.png");
    ImageIcon food = new ImageIcon("/Users/jessi/eclipse-workspace/updatedSnake/src/food.png");
    ImageIcon eagle= new ImageIcon("/Users/jessi/eclipse-workspace/updatedSnake/src/eagle.png");
    ImageIcon attack = new ImageIcon("/Users/jessi/eclipse-workspace/updatedSnake/src/attack.png");
    int length = 3;
    int score = 0;
    int live=3;
    
    int[] snakex = new int[1000]; 
    int[] snakey = new int[1000];
    int eaglex=75;
    int eagley=100;
    int attackx;
    int attacky;
    String fx="R";//Direction R,L,U,D
    boolean isStarted= false;
    boolean isFailed = false;
    
    boolean attackOn = false;
    Timer timer = new Timer(120,this);//set game speed
    int foodx;
    int foody;
    Random rand = new Random();
    public Panel() {
        initSnake();
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        timer.start();
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics game) {
        super.paintComponent(game);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);    
        title.paintIcon(this,game,25,11);
        game.fillRect(25,75,850,600);
        game.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        game.drawString("Length: " + length,750,35); 
        game.drawString("Score: " + score, 750, 50);
        if(fx =="R") {
        right.paintIcon(this, game, snakex[0], snakey[0]);
        }else if(fx=="L") {
            left.paintIcon(this, game, snakex[0], snakey[0]);
        }else if(fx=="D") {
            down.paintIcon(this, game, snakex[0], snakey[0]);
        }else if(fx=="U") {
            up.paintIcon(this, game, snakex[0], snakey[0]);
        }
        for(int i= 1; i<length;i++) {
            body.paintIcon(this, game, snakex[i], snakey[i]);
        }
        if(attackOn==true) {
            attack.paintIcon(this,game,attackx,attacky);
        }
    
            eagle.paintIcon(this,game,eaglex,eagley);
    
        
        food.paintIcon(this, game, foodx, foody);
         if(isStarted==false) {
        game.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        game.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD,30));
        game.drawString("Press Space to Start Game",300,300);
        }
         if(isFailed==true) {
                game.setColor(Color.RED);
                game.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD,30));
                game.drawString("Your fail! Press Space to Restart Game",200,300);
                }
    }
    public void initSnake() {
        length =3 ;
        snakex[0] = 100;
        snakey[0] = 300;
        snakex[1] =75;
        snakey[1] =300;
        snakex[2] = 50;
        snakey[2]=300;
        foodx = 50+25*rand.nextInt(32);
        foody =100+25*rand.nextInt(22);
        fx="R";
        score=0;
        attackOn=false;
        eagley=75;
        eaglex=25+25*rand.nextInt(34);
    
    }//initialization game
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        
        
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if(keyCode== KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            if(isFailed) {
                isFailed = false;
                initSnake();
                
                
            }else {
                isStarted=!isStarted;
            }
            repaint();
        }
        else if(keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT&&fx!="R") {
            fx="L";
        }else if(keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT&&fx!="L") {
            fx="R";
        }else if(keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_UP&&fx!="D") {
            fx="U";
        }else if(keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN&&fx!="U") {
            fx="D";
        }else if(keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_A&&attackOn !=true) {
            if(length>2) {
            attackOn = true;
            attackx=snakex[0];
            attacky=snakey[0];
            
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    
        
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(isStarted&&!isFailed) {
        for(int i=length-1;i>0;i--) {
            snakex[i]=snakex[i-1];
            snakey[i]=snakey[i-1];
        }
        
            if(attacky>50)
            {
                attacky-=25;
                
            }
            else if(attacky<=50){
                attackOn=false;
            } 
        if(eagley<625) {
            eagley+=25;
            }
        else if(eagley>=625) {
            eagley=75;
            eaglex=25+25*rand.nextInt(34);
        }
        if(attackx==eaglex&&attacky==eagley) {
            attackOn=false;
            eagley=75;
            eaglex=25+25*rand.nextInt(34);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
            if(snakex[i]==eaglex&&snakey[i]==eagley) {
                isFailed=true;
            }
            }
        if(fx=="R") {
            snakex[0] = snakex[0]+25;
            if(snakex[0]>825) {
                isFailed =true;
                /*if you want game continues
                 * live--;
                 * snakex[0]=25;
                 */
            }
            }
        else if(fx=="L") {
            snakex[0] = snakex[0]-25;
            if(snakex[0]<50) {
                isFailed =true;
                /*if you want game continues
                 * live--;
                 * snakex[0]=850;
                 */
            }
        }else if(fx=="U") {
            snakey[0] = snakey[0]-25;
            if(snakey[0]<100) {
                isFailed =true;
                /*if you want game continues
                 * live--;
                 * snakey[0]=600;
                 */
            }
        }else if(fx=="D") {
            snakey[0] = snakey[0]+25;
            if(snakey[0]>625) {
                isFailed =true;
                /*if you want game continues
                live--;
                snakey[0]=75;
                */
            }
        }
        
        if(snakex[0]==foodx&&snakey[0]==foody) {
            length++;
            snakex[length-1]=snakex[length-2];
            snakey[length-1]=snakey[length-2];
            score=score+10;
            foodx = 50+25*rand.nextInt(32);
            foody =100+25*rand.nextInt(22);
        }
        
        for(int i=1;i<length;i++) {
            if(snakex[i]==snakex[0]&&snakey[i]==snakey[0]) {
                isFailed =true;
            }
        }
        repaint();
        }
        
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Runnersnack {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(10,10,900,720);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new Panel());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no way to simply "convert" a Swing application to JavaFX. You will need to rewrite the Swing code to utilize the JavaFX API instead. So it will take some work on your part beyond just hoping to click a button and have it done for you.

Comment: That being said, there are plenty of guides online that will help you write the conversions yourself, including [this simple answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906779/converting-from-swing-to-javafx) on Stack Overflow itself.

Comment: Bear in mind that this site is for asking specific technical questions. Start the conversion process on your own. Post a question when you run into something you don't understand. Don't post a question hoping that someone can boil a massive topic down into a couple of paragraphs -- that's never going to happen.